# C Storing Huge Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I've been learning C for a few days and am stuck. I'm playing around with creating huge arrays (several GB) and cannot seem to create an array that's bigger than 2GB. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
#include <math.h>                                                               

/* Exploring 1d array sizes in c */                                             

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    int i;       
    double mbs;                                                                 
    int arr_length = 260000000;                                                 
    int arr_size = sizeof(double) * arr_length;                                 
    double *arr = malloc(arr_size);                                             

    for(i = 0; i < arr_length; i++)                                             
        arr[i] = (double)i;                                                     

    /* Print array size */                                                      
    arr_size = (double)arr_size;                                                
    mbs = (double)arr_size / pow(1024.0, 2);                                    
    printf("The size of the array is %1.1f megabytes. \n", mbs);                

    return 0;                                                                     
}
```

When I run the code, I get a reasonable result:

```
:~/c-examples> gcc -o array-size array-size2.c
:~/c-examples> ./array-size 
The size of the array is 1983.6 megabytes.
```

However, if I increase arr_length to 270000000 (270 million), I get a segmentation fault even though the array would be just over 2GB in size. I'm currently running 64 bit OpenSuse 13.1, and have 6GB of RAM:

```
:~/c-examples> free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5.6G       910M       4.7G        27M        12M       377M
-/+ buffers/cache:       520M       5.1G
Swap:         2.0G       307M       1.7G
```

I was hoping to eventually be able to store arrays of size 10-12GB (after adding more RAM), but want to make sure I understand exactly what's going on before. Thanks again for your time - and suggestions (an criticism!) is most welcome.

Comment: Are you sure your GCC is 64-bit, too? A 64-bit OS doesn't necessarily equate to a 64-bit compiler, as my 64-bit Win7 setup with 32-bit MinGW GCC can testify. If your GCC is creating a 32-bit build, 32-bit restrictions will apply.

Comment: this really feels like an issue linked to compiling on 32 bits, as 2**32 == 4.3G and if you're using an int somewhere instead of a uint, it will be maxed exactly around 2.15G

Comment: The problem is that you are overflowing arr_size beyond the maximum 32-bit positive integer value when you change arr_length to 270000000, and you end up passing a negative size to malloc, which will then return NULL.  If you change the declaration of arr_size from an 'int' to 'size_t', you will then see that you can successfully allocate the memory you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, arr_size was indeed incorrectly defined as an int, I feel quite dumb for missing that. Thanks again!

Comment: BTW: When code prints size_t, use `size_t sz; printf("%zu\n", sz);`

Comment: @mkimbal "passing a negative size to malloc, which will then return NULL" - do not think this is correct.  The argument to `malloc()` is type `size_t` (an unsigned type) - it can't get a negative value.  I think the calculation for `arr_size` mathematically overflowed.  The lower 32-bits of this calculation store in an `int` as positive or negative, given to `malloc()` results in insufficient memory for the following `for` loop thus seg fault.

Comment: @chux - Yes, you are right.  The negative value stored in arr_size is converted to a very large positive value, due to sign extension, when implicitly cast to size_t as malloc is called.  malloc fails because there isn't enough address space to satisfy the allocation for what appears to be a very large number after implicit conversion.

Comment: @mkimbal Thanks - I was a little fuzzy too on promotion from `int` (32) to `size_t` (64) - forgot that it goes `int` to `long` to `long long` to `unsigned long long` (aka `size_t` (64)) on this system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is 32 bit on x86 linux, even in 64 bit mode. It means that int cannot hold values larger than 2^31-1 (i.e. 2G)

Try to change the type of `arr_length` and `arr_size` to `size_t`

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it arr_size was overflowing by just a bit - I feel stupid for not realizing that. I've changed the variable types to size_t and everything works great. Thanks a lot!!